# Windows 7 optimization technique

Tags: windows-7, performance

I am a system administrator for a corporation. Our marketing department has been complaining about computer performance. After looking into the complaints I discovered that they have to do with copying large video files to their computers. In Windows 7 there is an optimization technique to use to fix the problem, I just don't which one.

Comment: It would help if you told us what the complaints actually *were* and what the results of your investigation actually *were*. Just telling us what they have to do with isn't very helpful. Is it one machine? Many machines? Similar configurations? Different configurations? Copying files that are how big? Taking how long? Did it get worse or was it always this slow? Are the source and destination the same device? What method are they using to initiate the copy? And so on. And so on.

Comment: This is an example of an actual complaint: "I've been copying 40GB video files from my local hard drive to a share on another machine on the LAN and wasting from explorer. It used to take around 2 minutes, but it has gradually gotten slower and slower over the past few months and now takes about 5."

Comment: It would be better if the users view the videos with web browser, versus downloading them, unless they need to edit the videos. If downloading videos is required then upgrade the internet bandwidth to at least 90mb's/sec, or move then with flash drives from one machine to another.

Comment: David so sorry yes it is multiple machines

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you need to do is identify the bottleneck, then fix it.  If they are moving large video files between computers it's possible your network is the bottleneck.  If they are copying large files around the same computer almost definitely the hard disk is the Hard Drive is the bottleneck.  Any optimization setting is going to be far less effective than identifying the root of the problem and fixing it.

Copying files on the same hard drive gives terrible I/O, try copying from one HDD to a 2nd.

Your question makes it sound like they are getting the video files from some type of server, in which case the Network is probably your main bottleneck.  Make sure the computers are connected via a gigabit connection all the way from the server to the desktops.  Also, depending on how serious you want to get, you could try to force a UDP stream for the copying which has less overhead than TCP.  You could also try some compression techniques like tar or even re-encoding the videos before moving them.

Comment: I have not heard of bottleneck before I will look into it thanks

Comment: David so sorry yes it is multiple machines

Comment: "bottleneck" simply means the slowest point in the system.  If you can reduce the bottleneck (speed up the slowest part in the computer) then everything will run faster.